# Problema con CSS Grid, desaparece con align-items: center; en .container

Tags: html, css3, css-grid-layout

Tengo un problema, porque cuando agrego  `align-items: center;` en `.container`, el ancho de mis `divs` dentro de `.container` se vuelve `0`?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grid 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item1"></div>
      <div class="item2"></div>
      <div class="item3"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Hasta ahi aparecen mi grid normalmente con su ancho y todo, pero si pongo   `align-items: center;` en .container entonces la grid desaparece y al inspeccionar me aparece la altura del div, pero la anchura sale en 0, por que? También pasa con justify-content, con cualquiera que sirva para alinear de hecho

Comment: Lo que se vuelve cero es el **ALTO** y es exactamente lo que se supone que suceda. Para evitar que eso pase necesitas usar `normal` o `stretch`. Te recomiendo leer la documentación sobre [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#valores)

Comment: Hola Olga, solo para confirmar... que esperas lograr agregando Align-items: center? se trata de centrar que parte? De hecho si tienes un ejemplo a mano alzada de como esperas el resultado ayudaría.